# select2 with ajax not displaying results

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ajax, jquery-select2

I'm trying to retrieve suppliers with select2 and ajax.
So this is my js code,

```
 $(document).ready(function(){
  $('.supplier_suggestion').select2({
    placeholder: 'Search for supplier',
    ajax: {
      type: 'GET',
      url: '/search_supplier',
      delay: 250,
      data: function(params){
        var query = {
          q: params.term
        }
        return query;
      },
      dataType: 'json',
      processResults: function (data) {
        return {
          results: $.map(data, function (item) {
            return {
              text: item.text,
              id: item.id
            }
          })
        };
      }
    }
  });});
```

I got this in my haml (which called the js file above)

```
%b.tosca XXX
        .input-field
          = f.text_field :supplier_name, class: "supplier_suggestion browser-default"
          = error_for @ro_nonreg, :supplier_name
```

and this ini search_controller.rb

```
def search_supplier
    search = params[:q]
    search_pattern = '%' + search.downcase + '%'
    result_raw = Supplier.where('lower(supplier_name) LIKE ? OR lower(shadow_id) LIKE ?', search_pattern, search_pattern)
    result = []
    result_raw.each do |data|
      data_hash = {}
      data_hash[:id] = data.shadow_id
      data_hash[:text] = data.supplier_name
      result << data_hash
    end

    render_secure_json supplier: result
  end
```

what am i missing here?

Comment: Do you see the ajax request being triggered and data returned when you click in text field?

Comment: @JagdeepSingh I used ajax event handlers ajaxStart, ajaxComplete, etc and it returns well. How can i check the data returned? thank you!

Comment: @JagdeepSingh hi so ive tried `success: function(results){
        $("#test").text(results);
      }` iniside the ajax code, and the #test div didnt change

Comment: It means either the ajax is not being triggered OR the response is blank.